# Converting Christmas LED wiring from 2 wire configuration (+ve & -ve) to 3 wire (+veA, +veB with common ground)

Tags: led

I'm struggling if there is an easy way to convert wiring for Christmas LEDs from +- voltage across opposing LEDs (2 wire with positive and negative) to 3 wire with a common ground for the LEDs.

They get driven in different oscillating modes for the various twinkling patterns.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu6Kw6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Cut the trace between D3 and D4 and then add a new wire to separately power it.  If this is a string you'll need to repeat that for each diode in the string.

Comment: Yes it's a long string all taped up - so that's not going to be a viable solution unfortunately

Comment: Then you're stuck, no way to rewire it without changing the wiring.

Comment: are the two LEDs actually separate components? ...

Comment: Yes they are fairy light leds on the "rope" with the 3 wires wound around to make the rope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry that the question didn't properly set out my problem, I only asked a narrow sub question.

I've solved my problem of not having a 3 wire power adapter.
I bought the newer 2 wire adapter (aliexpress), and chopped the power supply board in half across between the power supply side and led driver side.
I thus replaced the damaged hv side of my 3 wire adapter with the hv side of the new two wire adapter.
I reused both adapter cases and connected them with 2 strand cable.